# Django Restframework “Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `section_type` on serializer `QuestionSerializer`

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

This is my model.

```
class QuestionSection(models.Model):
    section = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = True, blank = True)
    max_marks = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.section

class Question(models.Model):
    question_section = models.ForeignKey(QuestionSection, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = 'questions')
    section_type = models.CharField(max_length = 10,)
    questions = models.CharField(max_length = 350, null = True, blank = True)
    image = models.CharField(max_length = 10, null = True, blank = True)
    no_of_images = models.IntegerField(null = True, blank = True)
    marks = models.IntegerField()
    shop_view = models.CharField(max_length = 30, null = True, blank = True, choices=(('critical', 'critical'), ('major', 'major')))
    what_to_look_for = models.CharField(max_length = 350, null = True, blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}-{}".format(self.section_type, self.marks)
```

This is my serializer

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):  
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = '__all__'

class QuestionSectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    questions = QuestionSerializer(read_only = True)
    class Meta:
        model = QuestionSection
        fields = '__all__'
```

I am not able to figuring out how to do it. The API will be like QuestionSection fields and inside that Question fields will be there.

Comment: Likely bot your error but you probably mean to put a "many=true" in your QuestionSeftuonSerializer.questions field.  As to your error: have you made migrations and migrated your models?

Comment: Thanks @Nidal. It is working fine now. I forgot to put "many=True".

Comment: Yay! I guess it was the error :)